# Custom notification sound is not working on flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter, audio, firebase-notifications

I had implemented notification with Firebase, and the notification is working properly. But I need to play a custom sound for notification. I had implemented

> playSound: true,
> sound: const RawResourceAndroidNotificationSound('notification'),

and added sound in android\app\src\main\res\raw folder which is named 'notification.mp3'. But no sound is playing on notification works.

Also implemented code in the payload.

Code from main function flutter:

[image: Code from main function flutter.]

Code from Payload or server:

[image: Code from payload or server.]

Answer (score 0):

Reading [this](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/http-server-ref) it seems that it should be manage automatically (if you didn't use a notification [builder](https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-android/blob/a0e8c27bb60f82ac3dcae6ff1e3926d3b0ea4a69/messaging/app/src/main/java/com/google/firebase/quickstart/fcm/java/MyFirebaseMessagingService.java#L47-L90)) on Android but you have to specify the .mp3 extension too and put it inside notification field and not data one..

"sound": "alarm.mp3"

**iOS** behaves very differently under the hood but you can use a custom sound by setting the **sound:** field in the notification payload too. Anyway **.mp3** is not a valid APN notification file format, and you need to specify also the file extention.

"sound": "filename.caf"

Follow [Apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/SupportingNotificationsinYourApp.html) in order to forge your custom sound file for your app.